# Probability of getting (n+1) consecutive heads before n consecutive heads seems to tend to 0.33. Why?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

If you browse all the way down to section 5.3 [here](https://medium.com/@rohitpandey576/coin-toss-markov-chains-7995cb303406) (also included just the picture below), you'll see a plot of the probability that you'll get (n+1) consecutive heads before I get n consecutive heads (both of us tossing our own fair coins, so two independent sequences). As n becomes large, this probability seems to approach 1 in 3. Is there an intuitive reason for this?

[image]

Comment: How can you get $n+1$ consecutive Heads before getting $n$?

Comment: These are two independent sequences of flips. There are two coins. Let me clarify in the question.

Comment: Informally:  I have a $\frac 12$ chance to get to $n$ Heads before you do.  When I am in that state, I then have a $\frac 12$ chance of winning your game and a $\frac 12$ chance of restarting, ignoring the small chance that you are in the middle of a long run of Heads when I take my $(n+1)^{st}$ toss.  Thus $p=\frac 14+\frac 14\times p\implies 4p=1+p\implies p=\frac 13$.

Comment: I'm having a hard time with the second part of the expression $\frac{1}{4}\times p$.

Comment: From the $\frac 12$ probability state in which I have gotten $n$ in a row there is an additional $\frac 12$ chance that I then toss $T$ which effectively means that we are starting over, at which point my probability is again $p$, just as at the start.  Thus along that path I win with probability $\frac 12\times \frac 12\times p$.

Comment: To be clear, I am ignoring the (very small) probability that my decisive $(n+1)^{st}$ toss comes in the middle of a long streak of Heads you are throwing.  In that unlikely situation you would have an edge on our continued game.  But if $n$ is large it is extremely unlikely that we are both in the middle of long strings at the same time.

Comment: Got it. I think this could have been an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is large, the chance of a run of $n$ heads is very small, $2^{-n}$.  We can view each flip as a try by me to start a run of $n+1$ heads, which happens with probability $2^{-(n+1)}$ and a try by you to start a run of $n$ heads, which happens with probability $2^{-n}$.  Almost all flips will fail for both of us.  We can ignore those.  The chance that I win is then $\frac {2^{-(n+1)}}{2^{-n}+2^{-(n+1)}}= \frac{\frac 12}{1+ \frac12} = \frac 13$.  The reason it starts lower is that we might both start a run at the same time, at which point you win because your run finishes first.

Comment: Cool, that turned out to be easier than I thought :) Thanks!

Comment: Can you please clarify this line - "Almost all flips will fail for both of us. We can ignore those"

Comment: Say we are playing a game where we flip coins and if one gets heads and the other tails that person wins.  We can just pretend that flips where we get the same side don't happen and only consider the cases where the flips are different because matching flips leave us in the same state as before.  In your game I am imagining out series of flips is predetermined and we can pick the ones of yours that are heads starting a run of $n$ heads and the ones of mine that are heads starting a run of $n+1$ heads.  Most flips neither of us will flip one of those.  We just ask which

Comment: comes first and ignore all the flips where neither one of use succeeds because those leave us in the same state as before.  It is like you have a coin that flips heads once in $2^n$ and I have a coin that is $2^{n+1}$ and we ask who gets heads first, but you win ties and we tie if mine is one before yours.  If $n$ is large there will be very few ties.